# Are the DC webcomics part of a larger canon?

Tags: dc, batman, vixen

There are three DC webcomics I know about:

- [Batman: Wayne Family Adventures](https://m.webtoons.com/en/slice-of-life/batman-wayne-family-adventures/list?title_no=3180&page=1)
- [Vixen: NYC](https://m.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/vixen-nyc/list?title_no=4169)
- [Zatanna & the Ripper](https://m.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/zatanna-and-the-ripper/list?title_no=4518)

(All ongoing, free-to-read series on WEBTOON.)

It's not clear to me where they stand in relation to other DC works, or even in relation to each other. They clearly reference the greater DC body of works, but what's canon and what's just inspiration?

There are some possible connections within the series. Vixen (and friends) appeared in WFA. Batman appeared in V:NYC, and another episode (featuring Teen Titans Beast Boy and Raven) name dropped Robin. However, these episodes give me the impression that the series have different timelines and represent different canons. Batman in V:NYC, for example, seemed to be a fairly generic portrayal, with little to tie him to his depiction in WFA.

(I can't comment much on Zatanna since I haven't read much. But the premise of the series makes me think there's not many opportunities for crossovers.)

So what's canon?

Answer (score 4):

In a word, no. These web-comics are their own comic universe.

> Marie Javins says, “We’re excited to continue expanding DC’s
> storytelling, with **fun, out-of-continuity stories** featuring our
> characters in different worlds and genres, that any fan, whether new
> to DC or not, can dive into.”
>
> Our collaboration with DC continues to bring some of the most exciting
> characters from the DC pantheon to a new generation of comic fans,
> complete with fresh storylines and new takes on classic heroes. Our
> work with DC has seen incredible support from fans and industry peers,
> and we can’t wait to share the latest series with readers,” added
> David Lee.
>
> These two comics were originally announced in April last year. The
> previous collaborations of the companies include Jasmine Walls and
> Manou Azumi’s Vixen: NYC and the Eisner-nominated series Batman: Wayne
> Family Adventures, which is a comical take on the Dark Knight and the
> heroes built around him. As Webtoon and DC’s first-ever collaborative
> project, the serial debuted in 2021, and new chapters have since been
> released every week.
>
> <sub><sup>[Webtoon, in collaboration with DC, announces two new comic titles ‘Red Hood: Outlaws’ and ‘Zatanna and The Ripper’](https://www.animationxpress.com/comics/webtoon-in-collaboration-with-dc-announces-two-new-comic-titles-red-hood-outlaws-and-zatanna-and-the-ripper/)</sup></sub>

As such, they're only canon ***to each webtoon***, not the wider DC universe and not even to each other, although these are fully licenced products, so there's always the possibility of a crossover into the other webtoons (noting that they do have multiple '*nods*' to each other and easter eggs) or an even more slim chance that they'll appear in the comic mainstream universe.